# Does the use of "proverbial" make sense?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I'm writing an essay on feminism. Does the expression:

> Men were running the **proverbial** show

make sense?

Comment: Not really. Not unless you have context to explain in what way 'the show' is somehow related to a proverb.

Comment: I wonder whether you mean "metaphoric" — but, generally, when you use a metaphor, you don't say that you're using a metaphor.

Comment: @Scott 'proverbial' is the way you say it though.

Comment: @Mitch: Perhaps you should be addressing your remark to IanS.

Comment: @Scott No, I meant that comment for you. No one says "Men were running the metaphorical show". People do say things like "Men were running the proverbial show"

Comment: @Mitch: And my point is that IanS said the opposite: that "Men were running the proverbial show" does not make sense (in the absence of a *specific **proverb*** that's relevant to the context), so you are contradicting him. Oh, and PS: I never said that "Men were running the metaphorical show" was correct. Quite the opposite; I suggested that, even if "the show" is a metaphor, "when you use a metaphor, you don't say that you're using a metaphor."

Comment: I don't think that the "proofreading" close reason was originally intended to apply to questions like "Does the expression, 'Men were running the proverbial show' make sense?" It seems to me that the poster, while happening to be writing an essay, fell into a particular conventional conversational wording (one using _proverbial_ as a kind of meaningless intensifier), thought about it critically for a moment, doubted that there was any proverb involved, and then came to EL&U to ask whether this conventional way of using "proverbial" makes sense. I think it's a legitimate question.

Comment: It's fine, grammatically and (apparently, at least) meaning-wise. **But** I'd knock off marks for style. As @Scott implies, it's insulting to think that the reader wouldn't realise it wasn't a literal show and needed it pointing out. And it hardly rates as mildly humorous ('the proverbial needle in a haystack'). But do you mean 'Predictably, men were running the show'?

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the formality of the arena for your essay. *Proverbial* literally applies to cliched maxims as in

> the **proverbial** needle in the **proverbial** haystack

referring to "As hard to find as a needle in a haystack". But it is used to refer to any commonly-expressed trope like *running the show* to mean "being in charge."  Here's an example that might have some resonance for you from [*Living Up to the Ads: Gender Fictions of the 1920s*](https://books.google.com/books?id=eFgZa0zW4tcC&pg=PA105&dq=%22the%20proverbial%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9_JqBiejOAhXDpR4KHelUC1k4KBDoAQgtMAM#v=onepage&q=%22the%20proverbial%22&f=false) by Simone Weil Davis:

> Often enough, a beautiful woman poses next to the product in an ad....
>   This "Carol Merrill" figure draping herself across the **proverbial**
>   car hood in an ad can be viewed as the "vehicle,"....

There's no real proverb referred to, just a common advertising ploy.

---

*Carol Merrill was the model on the TV show *Let's Make a Deal* who showed the prizes to the contestants.

Comment: This answer hits the proverbial nail on its proverbial head.